# reactjs search bar with params endpoint

Tags: reactjs

here I have a problem when creating a search bar in reactjs.

// So, I have an endpoint like this

```
export const getCountPoiCategoryProvinsi = (provinsi) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    axios
      .get(
        `${baseUrl}/api/dashboard/v1/getCountPoiCategoryProvinsi?provinsi=${provinsi}`,
        {
          headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
        }
      )
      .then((response) => {
        resolve(response.data.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        if (error.response?.data.code === 404)
          resolve({ lists: [], totalCount: 0 });
        console.log(error.response);
        reject(error?.response?.data?.message || "Network error.");
      });
  });
};
```

// The code for the fetch is like this

```
const loadPosts = async (provinsi) => {
      try {
        setLoading(true);
        const result = await getCountPoiCategoryProvinsi(provinsi);
        setPosts(result);
        console.log(result);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("salah");
      } finally {
        setLoading(false);
      }
    };

    loadPosts();
```

// and the code in the return section is like this

```
{loading ? (
        <h4>Loading ...</h4>
      ) : (
        posts
          // eslint-disable-next-line array-callback-return
          .filter((value) => {
            if (searchTitle === "") {
              return value;
            } else if (
              value.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchTitle.toLowerCase())
            ) {
              return value;
            }
          })
          .map((item, index) => (
            <h5 key={index}>
              {item.category} + {item.jumlah_category}
            </h5>
          ))
      )}
```

When I try in the browser and type in the search bar the data doesn't appear.

the console doesn't appear either.

what do you think is wrong in my code? Thank You

Comment: pass searchTitle param to your loadPost function

Comment: loadPosts(searchTitle); still not work

Comment: Do you init searchTitle with a value. Sth like ```const [searchTitle, setsearchTitle] = useState("sometitle")```. And how you update searchTitle when you input from your website , i dont see logic code for this.

Answer (score 0):

According to your fetch code, your loadPosts function did not have any input when called so likely your getCountPoiCategoryProvinsi function return an empty array.

Comment: I followed the tutorial that I have on google and compared with their code to make it the same. however it doesn't work properly
do you have a solution, dude?

Comment: You are making a search bar with request on every keystroke in search bar, you need to pass the searchTitle value to the loadPosts function. 

You need to call the function loadPosts when searchTitle changes so you need to detect the searchTitle value when it changes